# how to ask ambari agent not keep quiet when install packages in ubuntu

Tags: ambari

I'm installing new service in ambari managed cluster. my connection to hortonwork's repo seems too bad, it took lots of time to install ambari-server and ambari-agent it self (onece i almost thought it was dead).

the problem is that when i'm installing new service (e.g zeppelin, it also requires install other dependencies), the progress bar get stuck at 26% percent. it confused me if the installation get stucked or it's just too slow.

the command

> ps -ef|grep apt

shows the the install is still there. only can't track the progress via /var/log/apt/term.log like normal apt-get installation (it shows the download progress).

the command shows the apt-get comes with an "-q" options which prevent me from tracking the log file.

so my question is that is there any place i can change the default behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-q` option is added to "`apt-get`" command based on log level of `ambari-agent`. I.e. if log level for `ambari-agent` is set to `DEBUG` then `apt-get` **without** `-q` option is executed.

You can edit `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/logging.conf`, in `[logger_root]` section comment default line `level=WARNING` and add `level=DEBUG`. Then retstart ambari-agent. Now if you install any service them apt-get without `-q` will be executed.

Note:

- If `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/logging.conf` does not exist then copy it from `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/logging.conf.sample`
- Ambari agent specific changed need to be done on all cluster node

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the -o option been removed after set the log level to debug. only problem is the log file in /var/log/apt/term.log still not as verb as the stand output of apt-get.